# how to find all documents until a condition met in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, find

I would like to find() any document in a collection from a skip value to a limit value for a condition, not all documents.for example, I want to get all persons until I find fifth person with black hair. not just five persons with black hair. How can I do it in mongodb?
Thank you!

Comment: So you what to go 5,10,15,20,25...etc and you want to check if in the 5th, 10th, 15th... etc document the person has black hair?

Comment: No, I just want to get all persons until I get fifth black hair person. Therefore there will be many not black hair persons in my new collection plus five black hair persons.

Comment: Just iterate the cursor until you find the required number you want. It's a simple loop that you simply `break` when the number of matches is equal to find.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get the start/end ids and then the documents for that range. Supposing you want the consecutive persons between first and fifth person with black hair:

```
var start = db.persons.find({"hair": "black"}).sort({_id:1}).limit(1).toArray()[0]._id;
var end = db.persons.find({"hair": "black"}).sort({_id:1}).skip(4).limit(1).toArray()[0]._id;
db.persons.find({"_id": {$gte: start, $lte: end }})
```